# Can I convert a system.string to system.object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there a way to convert system.string to system.object in PowerShell?

I already has a csv file that some users I want to remove some role assignmnents from Azure subscription. 
First off, I tried

```
Import-Csv C:\Users.csv | Foreach-Object {Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName $Users}
```

Where SignInName is a column in the csv file that has users I want to delete in the following format x@y.com, but it did not work in the meantime it generated no errors.
That's why I tried another approach where I imported that SignIn Column in a variable. Then, I tried to delete it:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select SignInName
Foreach-Object {Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName $Users}
```

As a result I got that error:
[image]

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Ofc there is, but what do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: I want to delete a specific Azure Accounts using PowerShell. I already have them in a csv file. So, when I tried to Import-Csv C:\Users.csv | Foreach-Object {Remove-AzureRmAccount -Identity $_.SignInName}, it did not work and generated no errors. So, I tried:
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select SignInName
Foreach-Object {Remove-AzureRmAccount -Username $Users}
and I got an error telling me that it cannot convert system.object to system.string

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. Edit your question to actually include most of the details you just put in a comment - it tells us what you're trying to do and what you've tried. And if the error is complaining about converting object to string, why would you think part of the solution would be to convert string to object? That's the opposite way around.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that Foreach-Object either has to be passed a object via pipeline or be told what object to work with using the imputobject param
Try this:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select SignInName
$Users|Foreach-Object {Remove-AzureRmAccount}
```

Or for in my view slightly more reusable code:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select SignInName
Foreach($user in $users {Remove-AzureRmAccount -Username $user}
```

Comment: Tried it but still does not remove the accounts

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select SignInName
```

You are technically still returning a table object, it is just a table with one column. What you want is a string array, so each iteration with foreach will give you a string:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select -ExpandProperty SignInName
```

You could then use your foreach line above or, IMHO, even prettier powershell:

```
$users | % { Remove-AzureRmAccount -Username $_ }
```

Comment: And to add to this, we could have a discussion about what you're trying to achieve with Remove-AzurermAccount. If you are trying to remove users from a directory, have a look at Remove-AzureRmAdUser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/remove-azurermaduser?view=azurermps-6.4.0

Comment: Tried it but still does not remove the accounts

Comment: Did you use the code above but with "Remove-AzureRmAdUser -UserPrincipalName $_ -Force" instead?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to delete a role assignment not the user itself.
So, I've tried it with Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment but still not working.

Comment: Try to separate the problem: Try manually running that command with a username and see if it works first. You can also try using the command Write-Host "Trying to delete $_" in the loop so you can see if the users are correctly read from csv

Comment: I get the following error when I run the Cmdlet for one user:
Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Convertfrom-string does it
And with parameters you can edit the names

Be careful though it can sometimes misrepresent the data and put objects in the wrong field